# How to get entries based on date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Using DynamoDB GSI Index, I like to return entries with the following condition: `exit_at` date that is passed after 30 mins of the current time. How do I archive this using query?

GSI example: `sent` is a PK and and `exit_at` is a Sort Key.

For example in the dynamodb:

```
{
  "exit_at": "2021-02-12T09:30:01Z",
  "sent": 0,
  "uuid": "ee1b0230-bfb7-1084-5020-8fef7gg6a86b",
}

{
  "exit_at": "2021-02-12T09:25:01Z",
  "sent": 0,
  "uuid": "gg2b0245-fgb2-5552-1454-g3gf7he6f4g",
}
```

Let say for example current time is `2021-02-12T10:00:01Z` only 1 entry should return:

```
{
  "exit_at": "2021-02-12T09:30:01Z",
  "sent": 0,
  "uuid": "ee1b0230-bfb7-1084-5020-8fef7gg6a86b",
}
```

I would run a cron every 5 minutes to get the entries to send the messages.

If this is not possible, what is another approach to change the structure design or solution in AWS infrastructure?

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that your data model already supports this operation.

You are using ISO-8601 formatted timestamps, which have the useful characteristic of being lexicographically sortable.  In other words, their alphabetical order is the same as their time order.

The operation will look something like this (in pseudo code)

```
ddbClient.query({
    TableName: "YOUR_TABLE_NAME",
    IndexName: "YOUR_INDEX_NAME",
    KeyConditionExpression: "GSIPK = :sent And exit_at >= :time",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
      ":time": "TIMESTAMP_HERE",
      ":sent": 0
    }
})
```

Your client application would need to calculate the ISO-8601 timestamp for 30 minutes ago and place it where I've typed `TIMESTAMP_HERE`.

Comment: Thank you. Let say you have 2021-02-12T09:30:01Z and 2021-02-12T09:35:01Z entries In the dynamodb. You run a lambda function at 10am to calculate 30 minutes ago this will return two entries instead of one. Maybe I need to calculate it in the lambda function to ensure each entry exit_at is passed after 30 minutes?

Comment: Correct, you would calculate 30 minutes ago each time the lambda